# Storing Pyspark Data in csv creating problem

Tags: csv, pyspark, export-to-csv

I am trying to store my pyspark output into csv, but when I try to save it in csv, the output does not look the same. I have the output in this form:

[image]

When I try to convert this to csv, the Concat tasks column does not show up properly, due to the size of the data. Given my requirement, it's necessary for me to store the data in csv format. Is there a way out for this. (P.S- I also see columns showing nonsensical values, even though the pyspark output shows correct value)